# SWFUpload_0_0. HTTP Status: 500

Tags: swfupload

SWFUpload Version: 2.5.0 2010-01-15 Beta 2
Flash Player Version:
Operating System: Windows 7, Windows server 2008R2
Browser(s): IE, Chrome

Description:
When I tried to upload a file of max 4 MB there's no problem. Only when the size is over 4 MB: See here the debug info:

---SWFUpload Instance Info---
Version: 2.5.0 2010-01-15 Beta 2
Movie Name: SWFUpload_0
Settings:
    use_query_string:         false
    requeue_on_error:         false
    http_success:
    assume_success_timeout:   0
    file_post_name:           Filedata
    post_params:              [object Object]
    file_types:               *.*
    file_types_description:   All Files
    file_size_limit:          20 MB
    file_upload_limit:        10
    file_queue_limit:         1
    debug:                    true
    prevent_swf_caching:      true
    button_placeholder_id:    uploadButtonPlaceHolder1
    button_placeholder:       Not Set
    button_width:             200
    button_height:            19
    button_text:              Selecteer

---SWFUpload Instance Info---
Version: 2.5.0 2010-01-15 Beta 2
Movie Name: SWFUpload_1
Settings:
    use_query_string:         false
    requeue_on_error:         false
    http_success:
    assume_success_timeout:   0
    file_post_name:           Filedata
    post_params:              [object Object]
    file_types:               *.*
    file_types_description:   All Files
    file_size_limit:          20 MB
    file_upload_limit:        15
    file_queue_limit:         15
    debug:                    true
    prevent_swf_caching:      true
    button_placeholder_id:    uploadButtonPlaceHolder2
    button_placeholder:       Not Set
    button_width:             200
    button_height:            19
    button_text:              Selecteer

SWF DEBUG: SWFUpload Init Complete
SWF DEBUG: 
SWF DEBUG: ----- SWF DEBUG OUTPUT ----
SWF DEBUG: Version:                2.5.0 2010-02-17 Beta 3
SWF DEBUG: movieName:              SWFUpload_0
SWF DEBUG: File Types String:      *.*
SWF DEBUG: Parsed File Types:
SWF DEBUG: HTTP Success:           0
SWF DEBUG: File Types Description: All Files (*.*)
SWF DEBUG: File Size Limit:        20971520 bytes
SWF DEBUG: File Upload Limit:      10
SWF DEBUG: File Queue Limit:       1
SWF DEBUG: Post Params:
SWF DEBUG: ----- END SWF DEBUG OUTPUT ----
SWF DEBUG: 
Removing Flash functions hooks (this should only run in IE and should prevent memory leaks)
SWF DEBUG: SWFUpload Init Complete
SWF DEBUG: 
SWF DEBUG: ----- SWF DEBUG OUTPUT ----
SWF DEBUG: Version:                2.5.0 2010-02-17 Beta 3
SWF DEBUG: movieName:              SWFUpload_1
SWF DEBUG: File Types String:      *.*
SWF DEBUG: Parsed File Types:
SWF DEBUG: HTTP Success:           0
SWF DEBUG: File Types Description: All Files (*.*)
SWF DEBUG: File Size Limit:        20971520 bytes
SWF DEBUG: File Upload Limit:      15
SWF DEBUG: File Queue Limit:       15
SWF DEBUG: Post Params:
SWF DEBUG: ----- END SWF DEBUG OUTPUT ----
SWF DEBUG: 
Removing Flash functions hooks (this should only run in IE and should prevent memory leaks)
SWF DEBUG: Stage Resize:190 by 18
SWF DEBUG: Stage Resize:190 by 18
SWF DEBUG: Button Image Loaded
SWF DEBUG: Stage Resize:190 by 18
SWF DEBUG: Button Image Loaded
SWF DEBUG: Stage Resize:190 by 18
SWF DEBUG: Event: fileDialogStart : Browsing files. Multi Select. Allowed file types: *.*
SWF DEBUG: Select Handler: Received the files selected from the dialog. Processing the file list...
SWF DEBUG: Event: fileQueued : File ID: SWFUpload_0_0
SWF DEBUG: Event: fileDialogComplete : Finished processing selected files. Files selected: 1. Files Queued: 1
SWF DEBUG: StartUpload: First file in queue
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadStart : File ID: SWFUpload_0_0
SWF DEBUG: StartUpload(): Upload Type: Normal.
SWF DEBUG: ReturnUploadStart(): File accepted by startUpload event and readied for standard upload.  Starting upload to /File/UploadMain for File ID: SWFUpload_0_0
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadProgress (OPEN): File ID: SWFUpload_0_0
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadProgress: File ID: SWFUpload_0_0. Bytes: 32768. Total: 4541051
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadProgress: File ID: SWFUpload_0_0. Bytes: 65536. Total: 4541051
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadProgress: File ID: SWFUpload_0_0. Bytes: 196608. Total: 4541051
.........
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadProgress: File ID: SWFUpload_0_0. Bytes: 4489216. Total: 4541051
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadProgress: File ID: SWFUpload_0_0. Bytes: 4521984. Total: 4541051
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadProgress: File ID: SWFUpload_0_0. Bytes: 4541051. Total: 4541051
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadError: HTTP ERROR : File ID: SWFUpload_0_0. HTTP Status: 500.
SWF DEBUG: Event: uploadComplete : Upload cycle complete.
EXCEPTION: description: FileProgress is niet gedefinieerd
EXCEPTION: number: -2146823279
EXCEPTION: stack: ReferenceError: FileProgress is niet gedefinieerd

Answer (score 1):

Open up your website/project `web.config` and add this.

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="20480" />
</system.web>
```

`maxRequestLength` sets the limit of allowed file size to 20MB. Adjust it according to your needs.

For more information, see *[Large file uploads in ASP.NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx)*.